# Speeding up Matlab DFTs with NAG functions

Tags: matlab, fft, convolution

I want to translate some Matlab Fourier transform commands [FFTs](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) and [IFFTs](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ifft.html) into [NAG functions](http://www.nag.co.uk/numeric/MB/manual_23_1/pdf/C06/c06conts.html). the DFTs are:

- `fft(A,n)`
- `fft(A,n,dim)`
- `ifft(A,[],dim)`

where `A` is a complex vector. For example `fft(A,n)` is`c06fc(real(A),imag(A),'n',n)`.

**Problem**: I'm having trouble finding appropriate NAG functions that do the same job as `fft(A,n,dim)` and `ifft(A,[],dim)`.

Context: I am using Bruno Luong's convolution function [`convnfft`](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24504-fft-based-convolution) to calculate convolutions of vectors with 1 million complex elements, `convnfft(A,B,'same')`. Luong's function uses FFTs to quickly calculate convolutions, and I want to speed this up even more by using NAG functions.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Few remarks:

1. MATLAB uses [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) for DFT (See MATLAB [`fftw()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftw.html)).
   FFTW is considered te fastest FFT Library out there. I really doubt NAG's implementation is faster. You won't get faster FFT than what you have in MATLAB.
2. I see you're using Multiplication in the Frequency Domain to apply convolution in time domain. I'd just note that it is not always faster thing to do. It really depends on the length of your filter compared to the length of the signal. If the filter is short you better do it in the time domain.

#### Complexity in Time Domain vs. Fourier Domain of 1D Convolution

Assuming the filter is of length m and the signal is of length n (Assume n > m).
Then, Asymptotically, the complexity of Tome Domain Convolution is O(mn).
Yet, to apply convolution in Fourier Domain one must make both the filter and signal to the same length and then the complexity is O(2nlog(n)).
Hence, for cases 2log(n) > m one better use Time Domain Convolution.

Since this is asymptotic analysis in practice one need 2log(n) >> m to have a real gain over time domain convolution.

Comment: Thanks @Royi. 1. I have already investigated `fftw` but there was little or no improvement in speed. 2. Sounds interesting. Can you provide some good references for this?

Comment: Hi, Have you compared FFTW to what? If you compared to MATLAB, as I wrote above, you won't see gains as MATLAB uses FFTW when you use `fft` or `ifft`. Anyhow, you can't get faster FFT than what inside MATLAB (Maybe, just maybe, Intel MKL FFT is better on some cases).